# How do I fetch data using user ID on StackAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, api

Is it possible to fetch data using StackAPI using UserID instead of "fromdate" or "questionID" etc?

I want to fetch the questions and tags used by a particular user.
What's the syntax for it.

I have tried

```
    from stackapi import StackAPI
    SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
    SITE._api_key = None
    associated_users = SITE.fetch('/users/{}/associated'.format(10286273), 
    pagesize=1)
    associated_users
```

But I don't know how to print data from it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how "associated" is relevant to your stated goal.

You are interested in queries like:

```
tags = SITE.fetch('/users/{}/tags'.format(10286273), site='stackoverflow')
questions = SITE.fetch('/users/{}/questions'.format(10286273), site='stackoverflow')
```

which retrieve details on seven posts,
mentioning tags like python and chatbot.

cf https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids